# How to use putExtra and putIntent for string

Tags: java, android, string, send

I readed a lot about putExtra but my application still doesn´t works(applicaton shutdown)
I just want to send my string value in my editText from the MainActivity to the AnotherActivity textView.
Here is my MainActivity.java.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    Button bn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("text", et.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
              }
        });
}}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Here is my AnotherActivity.java

```
enter code here
```

public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText(name);
}}
```

And here is my activity_another.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AnotherActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="107dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
    android:text="@string/title_activity_another" />
```

Thank you for answer. I am newbie :)

Comment: Please post your stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry, you have correctly understood how to use Intent extras.

The problem is, you are trying to find an `EditText` (with id R.id.tv) that is in your second `Activity`'s layout in your first `Activity`'s layout, and that leads to a `NullPointerException` in your `OnClickListener`.

Change this line of your first `Activity`:

```
final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv);
```

to:

```
final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
```